# How to expose a service in AWS EKS that is just accessed through API Gateway

Tags: kubernetes, aws-api-gateway, amazon-eks

I want to expose a service that is currently running in an EKS Cluster. I don't want it to be exposed to the internet just inside the VPC.

What I'm looking for is that I can access this service just using AWS API Gateway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This scenario can be fulfill by using a VPC endpoint to engage a NLB that front the service in EKS. Here's the [example](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/integrate-amazon-api-gateway-with-amazon-eks/) how to do it.